# Delphi TRestRequest array parameter

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, rest

This might be a simple one.

I'm accessing a RESTFul service with Delphi XE6 using RestClient components: TRestClient, TRestRequest, TRestResponse and THTTPBasicAuthenticator.

The service requires parameters which I have no problems adding:

```
RestReq.Params.AddItem('param1', 'value1');
RestReq.Params.AddItem('param2', 'value2');
```

With the above code on the server side it looks like:

```
{
  "param1":"value1",
  "param2":"value2"
}
```

However, when I need to send a parameter which is an array and I try:

```
RestReq.Params.AddItem('param1', 'value1');
RestReq.Params.AddItem('param2', 'value2');
RestReq.Params.AddItem('param3', '[v1, v2, v3]');
```

The service will reject it because the third parameter is not the expected array. Which is correct because it receives:

```
{
  "param1":"value1",
  "param2":"value2",
  "param3":"[v1,v2,v3]"
}
```

I know it looks very simple. Have switched RestClient.ContentType, have tried to manipulate the array. Have tried changing the parameter ContentType, Options and guessing the solution is not a game I like to play.
So the question would be: Using the RestClient components ¿how can I call my service with the following parameters?

```
{
  "param1":"value1",
  "param2":"value2",
  "param3":[
    "v1",
    "v2",
    "v3"
  ]
}
```

In advance, thanks for your time.

Comment: I have absolutely no knowledge of REST or JSON, so only a comment, but did you try: `RestReq.Params.AddItem('["v1", "v2", v3"]');`? It is the first thing I would try.

Comment: Yes, and the server receives:

Comment: "[\"v1",\"v2",\"v3"]".

Comment: Hmmm... OK. I have no better idea, sorry.

Comment: What if you set the `Options` for the parameter to `poDoNotEncode`?

Comment: @Graymatter No luck. Even when I set it to poDoNotEncode the server receives "param3":"[\"v1\",\"v2\"]" if I set the parameter to ["v1", "v2"]. If I set it to [v1,v2] the server receives "param3":"[v1,v2]".

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is setting the value after you have changed the options to `poDoNotEncode`.

Comment: I may be misunderstand what your needs are but I think you may be missing the {} and the name:value pair needed for each array item for a standard json array. It may need to look like this '{"param3":[{"name":"v1"},{"name":"v2"},{"name":"v3"}]}'; or something similar.  At least that is what the final result should look like, not sure what needs to be passed to the addItem method yet (if that is what should be used for adding an array).

Comment: That is also a valid JSON form, however it's not entirely what I require to send. Let's take a look at the real documentation: [link](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html). "Labels" is the issue I want to fix, and it's just an array of strings, there is nothing special about them, it's just that it surrounds every value with a double quote. I'm just realizing the same issue with the property 'publish' which should be _"publish": true_ or _"publish":false_ but instead the server is receiving _"publish":"false"_ (the value surrounded by double quotes).

Answer (score 2):

Done! It looks like I was doing it the wrong (or complicated) way. The service was expecting a JSON object and I was building it property by property. There is an easier way:

```
var aParam: TRESTRequestParameter;
begin
  RestReq.Method := rmPOST; {or rmGET, ...}
  aParam := RestReq.Params.AddItem(); //don't care about setting a name for it
  aParam.Value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2","param3":["v1","v2","v3"]}');
  aParam.ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
  //set proxy params, resource, etc.
  RestClient.Execute();
end;
```

And that will do! Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: In my case with XE7 I must write 
   aParam.Value := '{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2","param3":["v1","v2","v3"]}';

Comment: In my case with Tokyo 10.2, I used aParam.Value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"a":"b"}').ToJSON;