# Delphi XE5 : JSON Send from client TRESTRequest Body received as text/plain

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe5, rest-client

I'm Trying to send JSON using RESTClient (Delphi XE5, Windows 8) from client side. But on server side it received as text/plain data.

The JSON i'm trying to send :

```json
{
  "kind": "News",
  "group": {
    "id": "G01"
  },
  "title": "Latest News",
  "content": "this is the latest news"
}
```

Received On Server Side :

```
    ----------120515234155952
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    {
      "kind": "News",
      "group": {
        "id": "G01"
      },
      "title": "Latest News",
      "content": "this is the latest news"
    }
    ----------120515234155952
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    ya29.QQKUa6ZDsco2uDK2neuYdurolLF8LAPDjMZGTdF3bnDLOIgX1JQ8g-FxKtMLSF-gl=
    MDY
    ----------120515234155952--
```

The code used to add JSON to TRESTRequest:

```
var
  ........
  RESTRequest : TESTRequest;
  content : String;
  ........
begin

  ........

  content:='{'+
        '  "kind": "News",'+
        '  "group": {'+
        '    "id": "G01"'+
        '  },'+
        '  "title": "Latest News",'+
        '  "content": "this is the latest news"'+
        '}';
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('body',content,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY,[],ctAPPLICATION_JSON);

  ............

end;
```

I have tried to use another variations with no changes :

1. `RESTRequest.AddBody(Content);`
2. `RESTRequest.AddBody(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Content));`
3. `RESTRequest.AddBody(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Content),ctAPPLICATION_JSON);`
4. `RESTRequest.AddBody(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(UTF8String(Content)),ctAPPLICATION_JSON);`

I find out that when executing `DoPrepareRequestBody` method (found on `unit REST.Client`) `TCustomRESTRequest` only use `LParam.Name` and `LParam.Value` for calling `MultipartPeerStream.AddFormField`. It means contentType always empty and MultiPartPeerStream translated it to text/plain.

Is there any way to force its content type to `application/json`?

Comment: Your client sends wrong content type text/plain. It should be application/json

Comment: @iPathツ You are totally right but only repeating the essential part of the question :o)

Comment: Have you tried http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter.ContentType ? Other useful example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25047430/1022219

Answer (score 7):

You may try using a TJSONObject to compose the body:

```
var
  jsResponse: TJSONValue;
  jsRequest: TJSONObject;

begin
  jsRequest := TJSONObject.Create();
  jsRequest.AddPair('UserName', lbledtUser.Text);
  jsRequest.AddPair('Password', lbledtPwd.Text);
  RESTRequest.AddBody(jsRequest);
  jsRequest.Free();
  RESTRequest.Execute();
  jsResponse := RESTRequest.JSONValue;
```

On the server side the content type is as expected:

```
var
  jsReq: TJSONValue;
...
begin
...
    if (CompareText(Request.ContentType, 'application/json') = 0) then
    begin
      jsReq := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(s);
    end;
```

Comment: Was trying the same using Nodejs on server side and this has worked perfectly! For me the server was expecting a simple object and this solved it. RestClient Method is rmPOST and the rest are defaults. Using XE 10.3 Community edition

Comment: Wonderful! solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to force the content type:

```
  RESTClient1.Params.AddItem('Content-Type','application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY, [], TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to set the parameter in the request:

```
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Accept', 'application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
```