Delphi 11 RestClient Request fails with some errors
I've tryed to send 2 Values to an RestServer and get only errors. It does't matter if i try the bold Lines instead of the italic lines.
var JSONValue: TJsonObject;
begin

  RESTClient1.CleanupInstance;
  // Set up the REST client for the protected endpoint
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://xxx.xxx.de/api/xxx';
  // Configure the request for the protected endpoint
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
  RESTRequest1.Response := RESTResponse1;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := '/visitorcount';
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmPOST;
  // Add the JWT token to the request header
  RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Authorization', FToken);

**
  JSONValue := TJsonObject.Create;
  JSONValue.AddPair('studio_ID', TJSONNumber.Create(1));
  JSONValue.AddPair('count', TJSONNumber.Create(300));
  RESTRequest1.AddBody(JsonValue.ToString, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
**
* 
  RESTRequest1.AddBody('{"studio_id": "3"}', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  RESTRequest1.AddBody('{"count": "300"}', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
 * 

  // Execute the request
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  // Handle the response
  if RESTResponse1.StatusCode = 200 then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Data received: ' + RESTResponse1.Content);
  end
  else
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Request failed: ' + RESTResponse1.Content);
  end;
end;


I always get an Error 400 (Json Syntax Error 4).
I don't know how to format the strings, that the server will aceppt it.
The charset is utf-8 and contentType application/json.
The Post to get the token will succeded, but without any body.params.
Any Ideas??

Related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107947/ Try using RESTRequest1.AddBody(JsonValue); instead, ie add the TJSONObject itself, not a string representation of it.

Specify the exact error message and clarify which lines are bold and italic. Provide server-side expectations if possible.
