# error : use 'application/json' Content-Type and raw POST with json data

Tags: java, json, api, plivo

The error message

> error : use 'application/json' Content-Type and raw POST with json
>   data

is being appeared from cyclos application inside plivo console which a third API that need to be integrated in cyclos through

```
Gateway URL: https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/auth-id/Message/

HTTP username:xxx

HTTP password: **** 

HTTP headers

{
      'content-type': 'application/json',
}

HTTP request type: POST

HTTP request POST body

{
    "src":"+xxxx",
    "dst":"+xxx",
    "text":"some test"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on how cyclos application is connecting ?

Comment: Why `content-type` header seems inside JSON body? Header should be a key value

Comment: @Sambit Its connecting via Gateway URL and I can see above error in plivo log

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732832/6397798), the problem seems to be with the request missing the relevant `Content-Type` header set to `application\json`. Please add the code with which you make the request for further help.

Comment: @bracco23 Its already in header

Comment: Can you please explain how you make requests? Maybe show a relevant [mre]

Comment: The correct api is - `https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth-id}/Message/`         here {auth-id} is pathParam which actually is your Plivo AUTH ID which can be found when you login to your  Plivo dashboard.

Comment: @Nitika I used same already

Comment: @Muhammad Muazzam did you check this request proper work in `postman`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try sending header as `'Content-Type'` instead of `'content-type'`.

There are some implementations where field-names are case-sensitive (Like an age-old bug in PHP!).

Comment: Currently its `{
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}`